# Use Flink Prometheous PushGateway Repoter but happened OOM

Tags: apache-flink, prometheus-pushgateway

The FLink version is 1.12, I follow the step(https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.12/deployment/metric_reporters.html#prometheuspushgateway-orgapacheflinkmetricsprometheusprometheuspushgatewayreporter), fill my config, run my job in Flink cluster. but after a few hours, I find cannot see metric data on grafana, so i loigin server and see pushgateway log, find like "Out of memory" error log.

i dont understand, actually i set `deleteOnShutdown=true` and some of my jobs is closed. why pushgateway will OOM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem has always existed, However, it was not described in the previous v1.13 documents. you can see the [pull request](https://github.com/apache/flink/pull/16823) to get more info.

If you want to use push model in your Flink cluster, i recommend use influxdb.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).